# Cannot uninstall application in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall a driver for my laptop, but the installer says I need to uninstall the previous version.  When I try to do that, I get a message that says:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

I've looked at the permissions, and everything seems to be fine.  I'm also an administrator.

This is really annoying me.  What am I to do?

Answer (score 14):

*Grrr* Seems that the problem is that the ppl at M$ who write the new UI don't use the same backend code as the old UI.

I was using the `Apps & Features` widget in the new Windows 10 UI to uninstall and it failed.  Falling back to the old `Control Panel > Programs and Features` didn't have an issue.  SMH.

Comment: For future reference, this article has some great suggestions and information with [10 tips for removing a program that won't uninstall](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/10-tips-for-removing-a-program-that-won-t-uninstall-907471).

Comment: [Similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55404271/129130). AVG Anti Virus somehow interfered with uninstall via the new Settings GUI in Windows 10. Anyone who has the problem, get a log file and report what it says: https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-.

Comment: For the record: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2669244/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-when-you

Comment: Right on the money.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian! Saved me a lot of painful hours figuring this out on Windows Server 2019!!!! Have a great day!